# Understanding well the concept of *ceteris paribus* in practice

Tags: inference, econometrics, causality

The concept of [ceteris paribus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus) says that to calculate the impact of one variable on another, we need to keep everything else constant. I want to understand well how to do this in a hypothetical case.

I have a hypothetical scenario where I’m given a dataset with all possible observable and unobservable variables that affect a student’s math grade. These variables include study hours, sleep hours, leisure hours, income, and gender. I want to calculate the impact of study hours on the math grade using the principle of ceteris paribus. Using R, suppose:

```r
# First, let's create a random dataset for 100 students.
set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
n <- 100 # Number of students

# Generate random data for each variable
income <- rnorm(n, mean = 50000, sd = 10000)
study_hours <- rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = 2)
sleep_hours <- rnorm(n, mean = 8, sd = 1)
leisure_hours <- rnorm(n, mean = 6, sd = 1)
gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, replace = TRUE)

# Encode the gender variable as a dummy variable
gender_dummy <- ifelse(gender == "Male", 1, 0)

# Suppose the math grade is a function of these variables
math_grade <- 2*study_hours + 0.5*sleep_hours - 0.3*leisure_hours + 0.00001*income + gender_dummy

# Put everything into a data.frame
data <- data.frame(income, study_hours, sleep_hours, leisure_hours, gender, math_grade)
```

For me, the most naive way to calculate the impact is to do the following:

```r
# Now, to analyze the impact of study hours on math grades, compare the math grades for different groups of study hours.

# For example, let's compare students who studied between 9 and 11 hours with those who studied between 11 and 13 hours.
group1 <- data[data$study_hours >= 9 & data$study_hours < 11, ]
group2 <- data[data$study_hours >= 11 & data$study_hours < 13, ]

# Calculate the mean of the math grades for each group
mean_group1 <- mean(group1$math_grade)
mean_group2 <- mean(group2$math_grade)

# The impact of study hours on math grades is the difference in means
impact <- mean_group2 - mean_group1
impact
```

Note that in calculating the impact above we did not control the other variables. How to use Ceteris Paribus? How can we keep other variables constant in order to calculate the true impact?

I’m not sure how to apply this principle in my analysis.

Comment: Have you learned about linear regression? The line in your simulation that follows the comment `suppose the math grade is a function of these variables` is key in this case. Since you're simulating data, you can read the "all else held constant" causal effects from that equation. In general, you could use linear regression to estimate that function from observed data.

Comment: Yes, but linear regression is used for the most real cases, for example, when we do not have observable data. I don't want to use linear regression, because I'm assuming that I can hypothetically obtain all the variables that influence the math grade. Note, for example, that in the equation I am not assuming an error. For me, it is educational to first know how to solve this hypothetical case and then move on to more real cases.

Comment: If you have all possible variables and your model is correct and observations contain no error, it's just solving a system of equations. You would normally need k observations for k unknowns. That's not stats, it's mathematics

Comment: If the equations are linear in parameters, you use methods in linear algebra. If they're nonlinear you need more general nonlinear methods. A good book on numerical analysis or applied mathematics might have most of what you need. Some OR books may include some coverage.

Comment: Just as a side comment, I know your example is hypothetical, but in social sciences it is often unrealistic to think we have or could correctly collect all the variables that may influence an outcome. That's why the first suggestion you had was to look for regression, and not for a system of equations. If you're looking for a hypothetical example where a system of equations would work, disciplines like physics might be a better bet (but that's not my field, so no guarantee here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ceterus paribus" refers to a model assumption that, like all model assumptions, is an idealisation. In your simulation, "ceterus paribus" when comparing `group1` with `group2` means that you'd have to compare observations belonging to `group1` and `group2` *that take the same value on all other variables*. Obviously, using your model, you could simulate such observations. In fact you could even write down the model with fixed values for all other variables and then see directly how the comparison will play out "ceterus paribus". In a straight multiple linear regression model with independence of variables and no interaction, the regression coefficient will tell you about the "ceterus paribus" effect, and it will not depend on what the values of the other variables actually are.

Interaction effects will mean that the "ceterus paribus" effect of a certain variable depends on the values that other variables take with which there is interaction.

Dependence between variables will mean that it is still in principle true that conditionally on the values of other variables, the regression coefficient tells you the "ceterus paribus" effect, but that this is problematic to interpret, as the occurrence of a value of the variable of interest $X$ will depend on other variables, $Z$, say. In extreme situations it wouldn't be possible, due to certain kinds of dependence, to observe certain values of $X$ given certain values of $Z$, and therefore a statement of what effect such value of $x$ would have given $Z$ held constant at certain values would refer to an impossible event.

In a simulation this is normally not much of an issue, but in interpretation of the real outcomes of a regression it is. We'd talk about the effect of changing $X$ from value $x_1$ to $x_2$ with $Z=z$ held fixed, but in reality, outside controlled experiments, there may not be any way to change $X$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$ without affecting $Z$, so the "ceterus paribus" situation is artificial and unreal. (Also of course in reality there may be interaction that is not modelled, and other violations of model assumptions that may affect the validity of "ceterus paribus" statements.)

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Christian's answer (+1), I wanted to briefly address some of the "you can't/shouldn't use linear regression in this case because there is no error term" comments below the original question.

> I don't want to use linear regression, because I'm assuming that I can hypothetically obtain all the variables that influence the math grade. Note, for example, that in the equation I am not assuming an error. For me, it is educational to first know how to solve this hypothetical case

You *can* use linear regression in this edge case, and you will perfectly recover the ceteris paribus coefficients you desire. Linear regression works perfectly in this edge case with zero errors:

```
# First, let's create a random dataset for 100 students.
set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
n <- 100 # Number of students

# Generate random data for each variable
income <- rnorm(n, mean = 50000, sd = 10000)
study_hours <- rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = 2)
sleep_hours <- rnorm(n, mean = 8, sd = 1)
leisure_hours <- rnorm(n, mean = 6, sd = 1)
gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, replace = TRUE)

# Encode the gender variable as a dummy variable
gender_dummy <- ifelse(gender == "Male", 1, 0)

# Suppose the math grade is a function of these variables
math_grade <- 2*study_hours + 0.5*sleep_hours - 0.3*leisure_hours + 0.00001*income + gender_dummy

# Put everything into a data.frame
data <- data.frame(income, study_hours, sleep_hours, leisure_hours, gender, math_grade)

model <- lm(math_grade ~ study_hours + sleep_hours + leisure_hours + income + gender, data=data)
summary(model)

## You've perfectly recovered the coefficients (2, 0.5, -0.3, 0.00001, 1.0) in the true data generating process
coefficients(model)
```

> If you have all possible variables and your model is correct and observations contain no error, it's just solving a system of equations. You would normally need k observations for k unknowns

The quote above is correct, but linear regression solves that system of equations for you in this edge case, and has the added benefit of generalizing to the case with nonzero errors -- you don't need to use a special approach, unless you specifically want to.

To generalize from this zero error edge case, try adding an error term and varying its standard error. Since this is a simulation, you could try zero error (as you already have), and then consider a range of error variances, and see how this influences the variability of the coefficients recovered by the linear regression.